# Is it feasible to use a Script Component as the source for data from multiple Microsoft Dynamics CRM implementations?

Tags: c#, rest, ssis, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a dynamic list of logins and passwords for Microsoft Dynamics CRM implementations. I am creating an SSIS job that needs to retrieve multiple entities from each of these organizations. Currently, Kingswaysoft has an SSIS integration toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics CRM that I use for retrieving data. Unfortunately, using Kingswaysoft for this would result in at least 60 *Dynamics CRM Source* components, 120 *Sort* components, and 60 *Merge Joins*. Not only would this take forever to create, but it'd also be very difficult to maintain. I would prefer to:

1. Use a service to query the many Dynamics CRM logins and passwords I need. This has the benefit of working when usernames/passwords change without having to intervene.
2. Use three *Script Components*. Each retrieves all the data for one entity type from all organizations.
3. Use that data to do more things irrelevant to the problem.

Is this a feasible approach?
What tools would I need to accomplish this goal? (O365 sdk/restful queries/etc)

If this only works for Dynamics 365 Online, that is ok.

Below is an example of what I need to do for each organizations worth of data.

[image]

Comment: You could create a master package to retrieve the login data and call the "working package" in a ForEach loop container and parameterize your Dynamics Connection - not sure if this will work for those Sort and Merge tasks you need to do but you can parameterize a lot of stuff that way.

Comment: Thank you @Filburt, that sounds like a great idea. However, I don't think Kingswaysoft's Source Components support parameterizing logins and passwords. Source: https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-365/help-manual/crm/source

Comment: You should be able to parameterize the Crm Connection Manager's ConnectionString property (and as far as I can see UserName and Password as well) - this is what I do when configuring Project Environments for my SSIS Catalog, so I'd expect it to work at package level as well. Try Right-Click your Connection Manager and look for *"Parameterize..."*.

Comment: This is brilliant and exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: If you'd like to go for self-answering your post, feel free to copy from my comments and turn them into something useful for others out there.

Comment: Ok. I haven't got this working yet but I would like others to see an answer. You are welcome to answer as well.

Comment: @Filburt I have decided to store the login data in a Flat File. Can you tell me more about how I can use a Foreach Loop container to iterate through each one of these items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a (ForEach) Loop Container iterating a set of data you intend to use as parameters add the following items to your "master" package:

1. Add Package Variable of data type `Object` to your package - it will
   contain the Recordset with your parameters.
2. Add a Data Flow to read your Flat File Data Source
    (would work
   the same for any data source you can read in your Data Flow)
3. Add a Recordset Destination to your Data Flow, assign the package
   variable you created in step 1 to the `VariableName` Custom Property
   and select the Input Columns (top checkbox selects all columns)
4. Switch back to **Control Flow** and add the Foreach Loop Container
5. Add as many Package variables as you need to parameterize your
   worker package connections, tasks, etc. and set their scope to the
   Foreach Loop Container by selecting them in the Variables list and
   click the `Move Variable` icon (box with arrow)
6. Open the Foreach properties and switch to the `Collection` tab.
   Change the **Enumerator** to `Foreach ADO Enumerator`
    Select
   your Package variable as the `ADO object source variable`
    Leave
   the **Enumeration mode** with the default `Rows in first table`
7. Switch to the **Variable Mappings** tab and assign the column index
   of your Recordset columns to the desired target variable you created
   in step 5.
8. Add a **Execute Package Task** to your Foreach Loop Container and
   connect your worker package on the **Package** tab.
9. On the **Parameter bindings** tab, assign your loop-scoped master
   package variables from step 5 to the according Child package
   parameter.